# Check Status of BackgroundWorker Without Using the RunWorkerCompleted Event

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

My app sends a request to another application using its SDK. Depending on the size of the request, it may take some time before my app receives the response. If I send the request in the UI thread, it just sits there waiting for the response, making my app appear unresponsive. So I want to move the request to a BackgroundWorker and display a marquee style ProgressBar on a separate form that I use to report the status of work being done until the response is received.

But it is not feasible to the use the RunWorkerCompleted event because my app does many different things with the response it receives depending on what was requested.

I've tried a "While BackgroundWorker.IsBusy" loop using Application.DoEvents after calling the BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync method in the UI thread, but this freezes the marquee ProgressBar's animation because it is constantly looping until the BackgroundWorker is finished. And if I put the UI thread to sleep while waiting, this also freezes the marquee animation.

Is there any way to check the BackgroundWorker's status without tying up the UI thread or putting it to sleep? If not, is there any other recommended method of showing that the app is still working while waiting for the response from the other application? I used to play an animation on the status form, but there is no longer an animation control in VB.Net 2013.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `yourWorker.ReportProgress(...)` and `yourWorker.ProgresChanged += SomeMethod`?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a single `BackgroundWorker` with fixed event handlers, you can create separate instances for each request/response type in code, something like:

```
Dim worker = New BackgroundWorker()
AddHandler worker.DoWork,
    Sub(sender As Object, args As DoWorkEventArgs)
        ' Do something here
        args.Result = sdk.DoSomething()
    End Sub
' Also handle ProgressChanged here if you need
AddHandler worker.RunWorkerCompleted,
    Sub(sender As Object, args As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
        If args.Cancelled Then
            ' User cancelled (if supported)
        ElseIf args.Error IsNot Nothing Then
            ' An exception was thrown
        Else
            Dim result = DirectCast(args.Result, TheResultType)
            ' Do something with the result
        End If
        ' Hide progress bar here
    End Sub
' Show progress bar here
worker.RunWorkerAsync()
```

Alternatively, you could use `Async`/`Await`, something like:

```
Public Async Function DoSomething() As Task
    ' Show progress bar here
    Dim result = Await Task.Run(
        Function()
            Return sdk.DoSomething()
        End Function
    )
    ' Do something with the result
    ' Hide progress bar here
End Function
```

This would be better if the SDK supports Async.

Comment: Thanks, Mark, I was not aware of the Async/Await feature. I'll look into that. But if I use the Await Task.Run (presumably to send my request to the other application), won't that freeze the marquee ProgressBar?

Comment: @LarryStinson `Task.Run` will run the function in a background thread.  The `DoSomething` method will wait until the task completes, but the rest of your application will continue to run.  The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) explain the "magic" behind it all.  Async/Await works best with naturally async activities (e.g. I/O), but can be useful to free up the UI thread in the GUI application.